# CFA with ordinal variables: problems with the frequencies of one observed variable

Tags: r, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I'm running a CFA (10 factors, 103 ordinal observed variables, n=284) using lavaan library. I'm using RStudio with R version 4.2.0. This is the model:

```
library (lavaan)

modelshort<-'
comm=~Comm3+Comm5+Comm6+Comm8+Comm10+Comm19+Comm20+Comm21+Comm23
rc=~RC2+RC6+RC7+RC9+RC10+RC11+RC12+RC13+RC14+RC15+RC16+RC17+RC19+RC20+RC21+RC24
as=~AS6+AS8+AS9+AS14+AS15+AS16+AS17+AS18+AS19+AS20+AS21+AS22+AS23+AS24+AS26
vd=~VD1+VD2+VD3+VD4+VD5+VD9+VD10+VD12+VD16+VD21+VD23
ss=~SS5+SS7+SS8+SS9+SS10+SS13+SS15+SS16+SS17+SS19+SS20
loisirs=~Loisirs6+Loisirs7+Loisirs8+Loisirs12+Loisirs13+Loisirs14+Loisirs15+Loisirs16+Loisirs17+Loisirs18
auto=~Auto15+Auto16+Auto17+Auto18+Auto20+Auto22+Auto23+Auto24
ri=~RI2+RI3+RI4+RI7+RI14+RI17+RI18+RI21+RI22+RI23+RI24+RI25
asoc=~ASoc6+ASoc7+ASoc8+ASoc9+ASoc11+ASoc15+ASoc16+ASoc17+ASoc18+ASoc19+ASoc20
travail=~Travail1+Travail3+Travail4+Travail5+Travail6+Travail8+Travail9+Travail10+Travail11+Travail20+Travail22+Travail23'
```

When I run the CFA without specifying that all observed variables are ordered the model run and there is a reasonable good fit, here the code:

```
fitshortord<-cfa(modelshort,data=abas6)
```

On the contrary, when I add `ordered=TRUE` an error message appears:

```
fitshortord<-cfa(modelshort,data=abas6, ordered=TRUE)
Error in lav_samplestats_step1(Y = Data, wt = wt, ov.names = ov.names,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: some categories of variable `ASoc6' are empty in group 1; frequencies are [21 70 113 0]
```

When I try to see the frequencies of the variable ASoc6 (using the code below) R seems to not be able to read the frequencies, and when I check the frequencies in the original spss file those are [1,30,101,152]

```
library(plyr)

count(ASoc6)
Error in count(ASoc6) : object 'ASoc6' not found

count('ASoc6')

      x freq
1 ASoc6    1
```

I'm working in RStudio and I can see that the variables are correctly imported (from spss to RStudio)

When I remove ASoc6 from the model the same error appears for ASoc11 with the same strange situation about the frequencies.

Can anyone knows where I'm doing wrong or what the problem can be?

Comment: With 103 ordinal variables, you can't expect this estimator to work without thousand(s) of observations, not 284.  Try .  But if you have missing data, the discrepancy in counts is likely due to lavaan removing those (i.e., listwise deletion is the default `missing=` argument; see `?lavOptions` for alternatives).

Comment: You are right and I expected that the model can be not identified due the small sample size. However, this issue does not explain the discrepancy in the frequencies of the variable. the variable has no missing values. And if the problem come from the sample size the model should not be identified even when variables are considered continuous (instead I have a good fit in this case), or am I wrong?